# Errors with dynamic Array created with new after passed to resize function

Tags: c++, visual-c++, c++17

I am trying to implement a dynamically created array using `new` that I want to resize but the resize action is not working correctly.

This is an exercise on dynamic arrays, so I need dynamic arrays using `new` and not `std::vector`.

Here is my code :

```
int main ()
{
    // Build an application here
    int length = 0;
    int size = 0;
    int input;
    bool endAdding = false;

    cout << "Please enter the length of the new array : ";
    cin >> length;

    int* oPtrDynamicArray = CreateDynamicArray (length, size);

    do
    {
        cout << "Add an element (0 to quit) : " << endl;
        cin >> input;
        cout << endl << endl;

        if (input == 0){
            endAdding = true;
        }
        else
        {
            InsertElement(oPtrDynamicArray, input, size, length);
        }
        cout << "The array contains : " << endl;
        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
        {
            cout << i << ": [" << oPtrDynamicArray[i] << "]" << endl;
        }
    } while (!endAdding);

    DeleteDynamicArray (oPtrDynamicArray, size);
}

int *CreateDynamicArray (int capacity, int &size)
{
    size = 0;
    return new int[capacity];
}

void DeleteDynamicArray (int *dynamicArray, int &size)
{
    delete[] dynamicArray;
    dynamicArray = nullptr;
    size = 0;
}

void InsertElement (int *dynamicArray, int element, int &size, int capacity)
{
    if (capacity <= size)
    {
        ResizeDynamicArray (&dynamicArray, size+1);
    }

    dynamicArray[size] = element;
    size++;

}

void ResizeDynamicArray (int **dynamicArray, int newCapacity)
{
    int ** newArray = new int*[newCapacity];
    for (int i = 0; i < newCapacity; i++) 
    {
        newArray[i] = dynamicArray[i];
    }

    *dynamicArray = *newArray;

    delete[] newArray;
    newArray = nullptr;
}
```

The problem is that the array is passed to my `InsertElement()` function and then to `ResizeDynamicArray()` only if `capacity <= size`, but the array passed to the first function, is passed with good values, but with abnormal pointers in the array.

Example :

For an array of 3, I have :

array[0] = 1 --> adress 0x0004e300 containing value 1

array[1] = 2 --> adress 0x00000003 containing ???

array[2] = 3 --> adress 0x008ffb24 containing value 2

I really don't understand, it would be really great if someone could explain my error :/.

Comment: A std::vector *is* a dynamic array.

Comment: What you're describing is impossible. Your "dynamic array" is a plain C-style array - which decays into the `int *` you're holding. Its elements are _integers_, not _pointers_, and have _consecutive_ addresses (in multiples of `sizeof(int)` of course) - they cannot have the addresses you listed in your example.

Comment: I know that is good, but for my exercise, i have to not use vector :/

Comment: And i really don't understand these adresses too, it's my debugger who show me these :/
They are the references of the "dynamicArray" in "InsertElement()"
But this create a problem after, I get exception everytime randomly on resizedArray

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is here

```
void InsertElement (int *dynamicArray, int element, int &size, int capacity)
{
    if (capacity <= size)
    {
        ResizeDynamicArray (&dynamicArray, size+1);
    }
    dynamicArray[size] = element;
    size++;
}
```

when you call `ResizeDynamicArray` you are changing the `dynamicArray` pointer declared as a parameter to `InsertElement`. You are **not** changing the `oPtrDynamicArray` pointer in main.

If you want to make this work you need to change `InsertElement` to take a double pointer (just like `ResizeDynamicArray`)

```
void InsertElement (int **dynamicArray, int element, int &size, int capacity)
{
    if (capacity <= size)
    {
        ResizeDynamicArray (dynamicArray, size+1);
    }
    (*dynamicArray)[size] = element;
    size++;
}
```

Or you could do the easy thing and just use `std::vector<int>`.

EDIT now that I look at it your `ResizeDynamicArray` function I see that function is completely wrong as well. It's clear that you have some learning to do with pointers

Here's how `ResizeDynamicArray` should be

```
void ResizeDynamicArray (int **dynamicArray, int newCapacity)
{
    int * newArray = new int[newCapacity];
    for (int i = 0; i < newCapacity; i++) 
    {
        newArray[i] = (*dynamicArray)[i];
    }

    delete[] *dynamicArray;
    *dynamicArray = newArray;
}
```

You're not the first newbie to fail to understand pointers. Have a good look at the code above and compare it with your code. The main difference is that my code using a pointer to change **what is being pointed to**. Your code tried to change the pointer itself, which is incorrect. It's confusing because what is being pointed to is another pointer (the dynamic array).

Comment: Mmmmh I tried this before, but it wasn't working because i didn't knew i could assign a value like this for dynamicArray

Thanks it's working now, but the problem is now the deleteArray function, with an exception "Heap Corruption Detected".

I saw that i have to do the same, passing by reference, so i did, but it doesn't working any way ...

Comment: That's why i exercise specifically on arrays, i come from web developpement so it's super hard for me pointer ^^.

Thank you for your help ! :D

Comment: Aaaaaaaaaaaand it's working !! Thank you for your help, so the big problem was that i was mixing up between arrays of int, arrays of pointer, and pointer on int -_-.

I need still a lot of practice to understand it well.

Answer (score 0):

There are several issues in your code:

First, in `ResizeDynamicArray`, you allocate an array of *pointers* to ints, not an array of ints. `int ** newArray = new int*[newCapacity]` should be `int *newArray = new int[newCapacity]`.

Second, once you have fixed that, you need to write `*dynamicArray = newArray;`;
but you should free the old array *before* you assign the pointer to the new memory block.

```
void ResizeDynamicArray (int **dynamicArray, int newCapacity)
{
    int *newArray = new int[newCapacity];
    for (int i = 0; i < newCapacity; i++) 
    {
        newArray[i] = (*dynamicArray)[i];
    }

    delete[] *dynamicArray;
    *dynamicArray = newArray;
}
```

Third, you since `InsertElement` may call `ResizeDynamicArray` (which will give you back a new memory block), you need to alter the originally passed pointer. So you need to pass a pointer to a pointer int the function, just as you did with `ResizeDynamicArray`:

```
void InsertElement (int **dynamicArray, int element, int &size, int capacity)
```

adapt the body accordingly then.

Comment: But how your assignement work ?? It says me "Value of type int* can not be assigned to an entity with type int" ?? 

I was going like this, but because i didn't figure it out, i changed the strategy to this one (that is obviously false thanks to your explanation :O)

Answer (score 0):

I know the question is already answered but not the why.

You have to keep in mind that pointers are passed to functions ***by value***.
The pointer value, *the address it points to*, is lost when the function ends.
But you are still able to change the value stored at the address it points to by dereferencing the pointer.

To pass be able to change the pointer value, *the address it points to*, inside a function, you have to pass a pointer to a pointer. In this case passing a double pointer is synonym for ***passing a pointer to a function by reference***.

```
void Foo(int **ptr) 
{
    // Don't use ptr, changes are lost after function end as ptr is a local copy
    // Use *ptr to change the value of the pointer you passed to the function.
    // Use **ptr to change the value at the address the pointer you passed to the funcion points to
}
```

In this case you can change the pointer value, *the address it points to*, by dereferencing the double pointer once. Which applies to above answers.